# How do I create a vignette in Photoshop Elements 11?

Tags: post-processing, reverse-engineering, effect, photoshop-elements, lomo

I'm new to Photoshop Elements 11. I am trying to create a vignette effect on some pictures.

I'm using the Guided view with "Lomo Camera Effect" (but only the vignette option, not the lomo). I find that the default vignette Effect settings are too intense, and they don't allow you to tweak them in Guided view.  I'd like to use this effect manually. How can I do this?

Here's an example of the Lomo effect. I find it makes the photo a little too dark.

[image]

Comment: It would be good to show some example before and after pictures, otherwise you will only get answers from those that know whatever this "lomo" thing is.

Comment: Can you show the _before_ of that, too?

Comment: @Frantumn, that picture looks like it has a lot of vignetting applied to it. Also do you mean to achieve something like the pictures here depict? http://www.fotor.com/features/lomo-effect.html

Comment: Similar to that link yes. I want a shadow-like border, but without changing the colour on the rest of the photo.  
after reading a little more, the over all effect is called LOMO, but it's only the vignette that I want. I'll update the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the simplest way in PSE11 to create a vignette is to use the guided edit option. Under guided edit under Photo Effects there is a Vignette Effect choice. Once selected you can choose black or white, intensity and also ability to refine the shape.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a couple tutorials about layers in photoshop elements.

[TUTORIAL 1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6tD4bUn10HM)

[TUTORIAL 2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XtLb7DA4l80)

So after layers make some sense to ya

- make a levels layer.
- Paint the Layer mask so it is white on the edges and corners ( ideally make this the shape of the vignette you would like)
- With the mask selected (it should have a selection bracket around the mask on the curve layer bar,  if not: click the mask) apply a blur filter to this black and white mask.
- Now inside your levels (this is the other box to the left of the mask, click it and ) you should be able to drag middle level arrow down to get your desired vignette intensity.  Try moving all the arrows around to get different effects on the values in the image.

Answer (score 1):

In **Expert** mode:

1) Choose the **Elliptical Marquee Tool** and draw either an oval or a circle over the image.

Adjust the shape by using **Select > Transform Selection** and using the handles on the transform box to alter the size, adjust the shape or move it around. When you're done tweaking, click the *green check mark* to accept the selection.

2) Go to the **Select** menu and choose **Inverse**: to allow you to work with the area outside your shape (instead of the area inside it).

3) Soften the edge of the selection so that the line becomes less obvious, use the **Feather** slider to blur the border.  Click **OK** once you're happy with the result.

4) Colour the vignette using the **Edit** menu > **Fill Selection**. Various presets are offered, including Black/Grey/White, otherwise choose from the colour picker.

5) Either make a selection from the **Normal** option from the drop-down menu, or adjust the opacity of your chosen colour fill.

NOTE:  going back to the **Fill Selection** and lowering the selected opacity does not lighten the existing choice. Instead it *adds* the new opacity onto the existing fill, making the fill colour thicker.  If you want to change to a lower opacity, first Undo the Fill Selection, then redo the fill and opacity completely.

6) Click **OK** to accept the current settings.

DONE. Save your new image as you usually would.